# Java: How to handle bad method arguments?

Tags: java, error-handling

I'm writing a method with the following signature:

```
public void setCell(int index, String value);
```

The problem with this method is that the index parameter has a finite range decided at runtime, and the caller may accidentally use an out-of-bounds value for it. What should I do in this case?

I can think of three options:

1. Nothing -- let the whole thread crash and burn with an uncaught runtime exception
2. Immediately return if the index is out of bounds -- the caller will be unaware that the method failed but the program won't crash
3. Throw an exception / force the user to wrap calls in a try/catch block. This seems a bit overkill and tedious for the user of the method

In general, how do you decide which of these options to use?

Comment: What does, for example ArrayList do if you try to set an element at an invalid index? Read the documentation, and do the same. The option 1 is the right now. It signals the caller that it has a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: So, will passing an invalid index essentially be a programming error? These should usually cause an early and loud failure, but it's still best to use meaningful exceptions and error messages.

Comment: Yes, I suppose an invalid range would be the result of a bug.

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` and its children exist for this purpose.

Comment: (Although IAE isn't the only exception that falls into this category.  As mentioned above, `ArrayList` tosses an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` just like an array would)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'd want to throw an exception as early as possible ([fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast)) or let the exception happen naturally in which case it would *hoist* or *bubble up* to the calling method to indicate the cause of the exception rather than trapping the exception in a `try/catch` and letting the execution continue.

I'd also avoid option 2 which immediately returns if the index is out of bounds due to the fact that it's now impossible for the calling method to know if execution has successfully completed or not. in-fact this is a means of helping the program hide a bug rather than trying to signal it, which in a way relates to JB Nizet's comment.

It's better to keep the caller informed if the method being invoked successfully finished doing its logic or for some reason, it failed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

4. throw an exception

You can even implement your own exceptions. Which case to use depends on your application and application design. Having uncaught or unhandled exceptions is probably the worst case most of the time.

if you have an user interface you can usually handle exceptions and inform the user, if you are implementing library functions you'll rather throw them and pass them to a higher level.

Comment: This is what I meant to say with option 3. I'll edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: You should only catch exceptions you can handle; exceptions caused by bugs should be left to bubble all the way up (depending on your UI of course).